# Renaming the Chatroom [done]

Tags: discussion, chat

I would like to come up with a clever name for our chatroom. Anyone have any ideas? Keep in mind, this name should be something that makes sense within Graphic Design, IE, someone will be able to figure out what this room is about from the name of it.

EDIT: Re-floated question in June 2013 :)

2nd EDIT: The Chat room has been renamed to **The Ink Spot**!

Answer (score 4):

The Ink Spot. :D

Comment: As in, Rorschach meets Writer's Block? :-D

Comment: I hadn't thought of that. :) No, I was punning on "ink," the liquid used to create images on paper, and the old singing group The Ink Spots. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Ink_Spots

Comment: The double-allusion was crystal clear; the other just tickled my funny bone. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

I was thinking, other words for 'Room'...

'Lounge'... 'Suite'...

"**The Creative Suite**"!

Now Adobe aren't using it, there's no need to let a good name to go to waste...

---

"**Design lounge**" is informative, while sounding slightly decadent.

"**Design by committee**" since it's a place intended for endless discussion?

---

There's got to be something based on double meaning of "**-space**", but everything I think of ends up just being  inappropriate:

- "The Negative Space"... sounds bloody miserable...
- "The Whitespace"... sounds racially segregated...
- "space.gif"... maybe a bit too retro...
- "**Good use of space**"?

(any other design-commentary cliches with double meanings? "**Good use of type**"?)

Comment: "The Negative Space" has a nice kick to it. Yeah, it's not rainbows and unicorns, but it sounds quite cool nonetheless.

Comment: I like Creative Suite. Or combining with lounge, so Creative Lounge?

Answer (score 2):

- Client is wrong
- The proof room
- prepress room
- design mojo
- proof needed
- desiging daily
- Design Den
- Tracking the Design
- Fun Font Frenzy
- Marginal Padding required
- Padding and Pink

Comment: My vote goes to "Client is wrong". I'd instantly join a room with that name :D

Answer (score 1):

Graphic Design

<sub>I like it. It's clear. End of message.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

The chat has finally come back to life. We might now be too many yet, but hey! we are always there ;)

How about we re-think the name and description of the room so it's more appealing to other SE members? "Graphic Design" is, indeed, descriptive. But it's not particularly inviting. And we would really benefit from new visitors! So, my suggestion, and it's just a quick idea to get the ball rolling again:

### "Creative Den"

Answer (score 1):

### "Between Two Kerns"

<sup>...sorry</sup>

Answer (score 1):

• Billy Bob's House of Color and Type

• Not in My Bauhaus

• Doughnuts are better with Glazer

• Stroke and Counter